# Use file_get_contents() to read from a specific div?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to get the text from a div in this page:

```
<html>
<head>Hello world!</head>
<body>
This is a test!<br>Hello man!<br>
    <div class="special">
    I want this text
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using this code to get the content without any tags:

> echo strip_tags(file_get_contents('http://website.com'));

However, I would like only to get the content from the

> `<div class="special">`

from that page. Is that possible in PHP?

Comment: That's possible, use an HTML parser. Now go search please, there are tons of examples on SO.

Comment: There should be dozens of dupes of this, the above is just the first I found. Use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`.

Comment: How? I see those topics but they are too hard to understand.

Comment: @JohnBalls: Too hard? Basic examples are like 5 lines long. But you do need to read the manual you know.

Comment: The problem is that I am portuguese and I have 13 years old

Comment: @JohnBalls: Ah I see. Language is always a problem, unfortunately you need to improve your English because you are missing out on a lot of resources otherwise. In this situation improving English == improving programming skills. I 'm not sure what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTML parser to parse the object you read using `file_get_contents()`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/248065) lists a bunch of parsers you could use